# Make Meteor Reactive to Specific Subitem of Meteor.user()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

### What I'm Trying to Do...

I need to use some subproperties which are stored in the user's `Meteor.user()` object, such as `Meteor.user().profile.preferences.preference_one`, `Meteor.user().profile.preferences.preference_two`, et cetera.  These subproperties are being used inside reactive autorun blocks because there are recalculations that must be done anytime they change.

### My Problem Is...

I've discovered that when I refer to the value of these subproperties from within a reactive block, then the autorun is fired for *any* change to the `Meteor.user()` object, including changes which do not affect in any way the data that I am explicitly referencing.  For example, if `Meteor.user().profile.name` is updated, then any autorun that includes `Meteor.user().profile.preferences.preference_one` or `Meteor.user().profile.preferences.preference_two` gets fired as well, because they all have a common parent.

[I have seen a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324350/how-to-make-meteor-reactive-on-sub-items-but-not-parent) dealing with limiting the scope of Meteor's reactivity, but it deals with a custom collection, not the `Meteor.users` collection.  I cannot see how the solution there could be made applicable because they are specifying fields in subscriptions to limit what subproperties are published to the client, and in my case, I need all the subproperties of `Meteor.user()`.  But I need to be able to choose which subproperties I am reacting to!

Storing subproperty values locally and then comparing on every change would of course work, but it is a brute force solution solution in that it requires extra logic and that the autoruns will all be firing anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is the **best** way, but have a look at this example:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if (user && user.profile)
    Session.set('p1', user.profile.preference1);
});

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var p1 = Session.get('p1');
  console.log("p1 is " + p1);
});
```

The first `autorun` will fire every time the user data changes, however the second `autorun` will fire only when that particular property changes.

Comment: I agree, it is better than my naiive approach of comparing the value on change.  It's conceptually doing the same sort of filtering that a publication by fields would do.  I like it.

Answer (score 1):

David's solution is great (as always).

Just to offer some variety, I'd suggest moving your preferences (or the whole darn profile) to its own collection. Then, use a `.publish(null,...` to always have access to that collection.

Either solution will work great, it is simply my preference to have nothing except login credentials attached to the critical `users` collection.

Comment: On a more serious note I am still not sure this really solves the problem, since I do need to publish all the user properties, and I can't specify projection fields without losing some of them.  This would be true regardless of what collection I published from.

Comment: Hahaha nice, I'm not sure I follow though. you've got the users autopublishing a safe subset, and then you autopublish a `preferences` collection for the given user. The doc looks like: `{user: '123', p1: 'apples', p2: 'vanilla mostly'}`. Then, the only time DDP sends a change is when `p1` or `p2` is changed. Or you could go crazy & have 1 doc for each user-preference `{user:'123', prefName:'What flavor', prefVal:'Vanilla mostly'}`, although I'd call this overkill.

Comment: Putting user information in the user doc seems to me the most Meteoric solution.  I'd prefer to have a solution which tends towards this paradigm.  My motivation is that I have multiple preference parameters which will and must be independently varied.  There are enough parameters that the number of required documents gets kind of silly, and it seems more logical to use session vars auto-updating from the *one* document inside a *single* tracker established *once*.  I have a further motivation which is that the session vars are a bit easier to manage across different contexts than pub/subbing.

Comment: Of course, I think the MOST Meteoric solution would be for reactive variables to only trigger their reactive parent block when the specific property referred to in the block is in fact the property that was altered.  I agree this answer **is** a solution, but for a many-parameter system such as I have it is simply less maintainable than the session var work around.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but I often have the problem, and this is my solution ;)

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  const preference_one = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId(), {
    fields: { "profile.preferences.preference_one": 1 }
  })?.profile.preferences.preference_one;
  console.log(preference_one)
});
```