# No Reactive Update with Collection.find in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In a test app with collections `Fruits` and `Meteor.users`, a user clicks on the name of a fruit to add it to his favorite list, using server-side code

```
Meteor.users.update( Meteor.user()._id, { $push: {'profile.favorites': fruit_id } })
```

where `fruit_id` is the ObjectID `fruit._id` generated by Mongo.

For the favorite fruits page, the client also subscribes to a publication:

```
Meteor.publish('favoriteFruits', function() {

    return Fruits.find({
        '_id': {
            '$in' : Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.favorites
        }
    })

}
```

**Problem:** When a new fruit is made a favorite, nothing changes on the favorite fruits page unless a page refresh is made.

My guess is because in the publication code, the line containing `$in` is not reactive.

For this situation, what is the usual practice to enable the user to reactively see the newly added or removed fruits? Can `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.favorites` be made reactive?

---

The subscription is done in the controller, I'm using Angular with Meteor.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FavoriteFruitsCtrl', function($scope, $meteor) {

    $meteor.autorun($scope, function() {

        $meteor
            .subscribe('favoriteFruits')
            .then(function() {
                $scope.favfruits = $meteor.collection(Fruits, false)
            })

    })

})
```

---

Based on the suggestions by @SylvainB and @Billybobbonnet, are we trying to do this? The second autorun containing `.subscribe` does re-run whenever there is changes to `Meteor.user().profile.favorites`!

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FavoriteFruitsCtrl', function($scope, $meteor) {

    $meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        Session.set('favorites', Meteor.user().profile.favorites)
    })

    // This autorun block will be triggered when the above autorun is triggered
    $meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        var justForTriggering = Session.get('favorites')
        $meteor
            .subscribe('favoriteFruits')
            .then(function() {
                $scope.favfruits = $meteor.collection(Fruits, false)
            })
    })

})
```

However `$meteor.subscribe` function is not fired (by checking on the server side)

Comment: Could you tell us how and where your subscription is done? It basically comes down to making your subscription reactive to `Meteor.user()`

Comment: @SylvainB I've updated the question with the way the subscription is currently being done

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [template level subscription](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) using the array of favorite fruits as argument. It assumes that you exposes the `profile.favorite` field in another publication, but it should already be exposed by default for the current user.

Since you will wrap your subscription in an autorun and use a cursor from the users collection, the cahin of events will be as follows: 
updating profile > triggering autorun > updating publication of favorite fruits.

Comment: Yup, and there's even no need to use the array of favorite fruits (that way he or she can keep this check on the server side, which I am guessing is desired). Just check when the user is updated. And if you want to be more specific, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29753793/1439597).

Comment: Yet another nice trick from @davidweldon . Thanks for mentioning it.