# Force Subscription to Reload in Angular Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

How can we force a Meteor subscription created using `$scope.meteorSubscribe` to reload?

The only way I have found is to pass a reactive variable to `$scope.meteorSubscribe`, and change this reactive variable whenever I want to force a re-subscribe. Doesn't seem like a good solution to me, especially when this variable can be a huge array.

Is there a method  that is more proper?

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {

    $scope
        .$meteorSubscribe(
            'favoriteFruits', 
            Session.get('favorites')    // this is the reactive variable that we need to pass in
        )
        .then(function() {
            $scope.favFruits = $scope.$meteorCollection(Fruits, false)
        })

})
```

Comment: What is your purpose when wanting to re-trigger the publication?

Comment: @Urigo Thanks for helping out! The reason is related to this very last part of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339575/no-reactive-update-with-collection-find-in-meteor